# Get MyLocation using GPS - how to implement 'if else' statement?

Tags: java, android, windows-mobile-gps

I am new to android, and reverse-engineering my way into learning java.

Having got as far using the code below, i have a few problems needing to be resolved while customising it to suit my inentions.

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

}

/* Class My Location Listener */

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();

String Text = “My current location is: “ +

“Latitud = “ + loc.getLatitude() +

“Longitud = “ + loc.getLongitude();

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

Text,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

“Gps Disabled”,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}

@Override

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

“Gps Enabled”,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

{
```

The problem is my (android) home screen starts with a checkboxed page showing two choices (checboxes);

GPS On (Enabled)
GPS Off (Disabled)

Now, question is, i have no idea how to write the 'if else' statement/method which could which could help direct the 'On' scenario to the next stage of getting my location, and for directing the 'Off' scenario back to beginning (Home screen).

Where/how in the code do i declare/insert the checkbox code?

Any assistance welcome please.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the GPS On/Off to be chosen by the user or detected by your code?

Comment: OK so why 2 checkboxs for a single choice?  go left(on) or right (off)  Do you want one checkbox and if its checked startActivity and if its not do nothing? Then a button to go back or do you want 2 buttons "Get Activity" and "Go HomeScreen"

Comment: Thanks slybloty and sabanim, there is a default 'Off' on the checkbox, so that user willfully chooses to turn it 'On' so, yes, it is meant to be user chosen. If 'On' checked, then start activity. If 'Off' do nothing is true. And code should detect 'On' and start activity - yes. Not so sure about buttons though. Just want natural progression to activity, once code detects 'On' choice...

Answer (score 0):

Basic checkbox check:

```
 final CheckBox cbGPS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 cbGPS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                  // do this if checked

                  StartGPSMethod();
           } else {
                  // if not checked do this
                  // do nothing  or

                    EndGPSMethod();
           }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Sabanim. I will go check it now